# RequestError: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NetValue', table column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, null

I am trying to insert some values in a locally installed Microsoft Sql Server by using Node JS express.
Parameters' values are given from user input in the web page (created via ejs file).
I have read a lot of solutions in similar problems but none of them works for me.

Given values, such as company and data, are inserted correctly, but in the others seem to always parse null value to the database and I cannot understand why.
The connection with the database works fine (corresponding select query shows all rows)
Would appreciate any help.

The code is shown below:

````
//Controller to create an insert in the database 
exports.postbudget = (req, res, next) => {
    const company = 10008;
    const data = '02';
    const date = new Date(2022,01,19);
    const doc = 'Budget';
    const reason = 'Budget';
    const quantity = 0;
    const supplieruid = req.body.SupplierUID;
    const resource = req.body.ResourceID;
    const taskid = req.body.TaskID;
    const value = parseInt(req.body.NetValue);

    mssql.connect(dbconfig, function(err) {
        if (err) console.log('Error: ', err);

        var request = new mssql.Request();
        request.input('company', mssql.Decimal(18,0), company)
        .input('data', mssql.NVarChar(50), data)
        .input('supplieruid', mssql.NVarChar(50), supplieruid)
        .input('date', mssql.DateTime, date)
        .input('doc', mssql.NVarChar(50), doc)
        .input('reason', mssql.NVarChar(50), reason)
        .input('resource', mssql.NVarChar(20), resource)
        .input('taskid', mssql.NVarChar(20), taskid)
        .input('quantity', mssql.Decimal(18,3), quantity)
        .input('value', mssql.Decimal(18,2), value)

        // Query to the database
        .query("INSERT INTO [CostTransactions] (CompanyID, DataTypeCode, SupplierUID, CT_IssueDate, CT_DocNumber, CT_Reason, ResourceID, TaskID, Quantity, NetValue) \
        VALUES (@company, @data, @supplieruid, @date, @doc, @reason, @resource, @taskid, @quantity, @value)")

        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            //return result.recordset;
            res.redirect('/budget');
            //mssql.close();
        })
        .catch(err => { 
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.render('404.ejs');
            }
        })
    })
}```
````

Comment: Just a guessing, your users enter not integer but something else.
Can you log the "value"-variable  and see what it actually becomes, perhaps you need some validation

Comment: I guess the obvious question is: what's stored in `req.body.NetValue`? For example `parseInt('0.48')` will return `0` but `parseInt('$0.48')` will return `NaN`.

Comment: In req.body.NetValue is stored an input variable of type "number" of the ejs file (as the user give it). But the problem is not only with Value variable, but also with supplieruid, resource and taskid that also end up as null in the sql server (it just dont give an error on them because their columns allow nulls)

Comment: If none of the `req.body` elements are initialized correctly... how are you initializing `express` in your code? Are you using `body-parser` and/or the `express.json()` middleware?

Comment: Yes I am using all of these..(tried them standalone also) `var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`